# Laravel / Google Drive API rename folder returns 403 reason fieldNotWritable

Tags: laravel, google-drive-api

I felt optimistic when I've started investigate this issue because it looked like I wasn't the first one...

I have a Laravel app using Google Drive as storage. It works when I add / rename files using Storage facade.

To rename a folder I'm using `$googleDriveService->files->update($folder->getId(), $folder)` but I got an error 403 "*The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.*"

On the Google OAuth 2.0 Playground I have the following scope:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata (i'm not sure I need this one)

Here is my code

```php
    $client_id = env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_ID');
    $client_secret = env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET');
    $refresh_token = env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_REFRESH_TOKEN');

    /* Instantiate Google Client */
    $googleClient = new GoogleClient();
    $googleClient->setClientId($client_id);
    $googleClient->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $googleClient->refreshToken($refresh_token);
    $googleClient->addScope([
        Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE,
        Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE,
        Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA
    ]);

    /* Instantiate Google Drive service */
    $googleDriveService = new GoogleDriveService($googleClient);


    function renameFolder($oldName, $newName, $path, $service)
    {
        /* list all folders with $oldName and select the first one matching $path */
        $oldFolder = collect($service->files->listFiles(['q' => "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='$oldName'"]))
            ->first(fn($folder) => getFolderPath($folder->getId(), $service) === "$path/$oldName");

        if(!$oldFolder) { return 'folder unknown'; }

        $oldFolder->setName($newName);
        /* this is the line pointed by the error */ $service->files->update($oldFolder->getId(), $oldFolder);

        return compact('oldFolder');

    }

    function getFolderPath($folderId, $service, $delimiter = '/')
    {
        $path = '';
        while ($folderId) {
            $folder = $service->files->get($folderId, ['fields' => 'name, parents']);
            if($folder->name === env('GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER')) { break; }
            $path = $folder->name . $delimiter . $path;
            $folderId = $folder->parents;
        }
        return rtrim($path, $delimiter);
    }

    return renameFolder('old_name', 'new_name', 'path_to_folder', $googleDriveService);
```

When I comment the line with `…->files->update(…` I see the correct folder (I compared the Id with Google Drive) and the name is the right one.

I've tried as well `$googleDriveService->files->update($folder->getId(), $folder)->execute()` but I don't know what else to try… any idea is welcome

Comment: Can you provide the value of `$oldFolder`?

Comment: @Tanaike sure, before the line `$service->files->update(…` $oldFolder is a Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile object with a bunch of properties equal `null` except *id* equal to the folder id from Google Drive, *mimeType* equal to `application/vnd.google-apps.folder`, *kind* equal to `drive#file` and *name* equal to the newName. Is there any property I should look at in particular ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand your current value of `$oldFolder`. For example, from your reply, `$oldFolder` might be `new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(["name" => $newName])`? If my understanding is correct, I thought that if `$oldFolder->getId()` is valid value, the script works.

Comment: @Tanaike `$oldFolder->getId()` is a correct value indeed. I've added `return $oldFolder->getId();` before where the error occure, it returns the correct Id I can see in Google Drive. I get $oldFolder with `$service->files->listFiles(['q' => "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='$oldName'"])`

Comment: @Tanaike thx you made me on the right track. When using `file->update(…` 2nd parameter should be a new metadata object

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that my understanding was correct. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tanaike comments, I understood the problem came from

```php
$service->files->update($oldFolder->getId(), $oldFolder);
```

the 2nd parameter of update method shouldn't be `$oldFolder` but a new metadata object.

I've replaced

```php
$oldFolder->setName($newName);
$service->files->update($oldFolder->getId(), $oldFolder);
```

by

```php
$newMetadata = new GoogleServiceDriveDriveFile(['name' => $newName]);
$service->files->update($oldFolder->getId(), $newMetadata);
```

And it works.